# Indirection requires pointer operand. I dont understand why *uptr is working

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

I don't understand why get value from address. ex) 
cout<<*ptr<

This project is writing unique pointer library with template. in my template.cpp, I can cout my value with using *ptr. But it is not working for my main().

```
template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr<T>::my_unique_ptr(T *input)
{
    my_ptr = input;
    std::cout<<*my_ptr<<std::endl; // a
    std::cout<<&my_ptr<<std::endl; // 0x7ffee7b427e0
}
```

but.. in my main()`

```
int main()
{
    my_unique_ptr<char> uptr{new char{'a'}};
    cout<<"address of uptr: "<<&uptr<<endl; //0x7ffee7b427e0
    cout<<*uptr<<endl; //error
    return 0;
}
```

and the error is

```
Indirection requires pointer operand ('my_unique_ptr<char>' invalid)
```

this is "my_memory.cpp"

```
#include "my_memory.hpp"
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr<T>::my_unique_ptr(): my_ptr(nullptr)
{//there are no valye for my_ptr since it is nullptr
    std::cout<<"**** Default Con Start ****"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"my_ptr: "<<my_ptr<<" address: "<<&my_ptr<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"--------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr<T>::~my_unique_ptr()
{
    std::cout<<"**** Destructor ****"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&my_ptr<<std::endl;
    delete my_ptr;
}

template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr<T>::my_unique_ptr(T *input)
{
    my_ptr = input;
   // my_ptr = new char{*input};
    //this->my_ptr = new
    std::cout<<*my_ptr<<std::endl; //value of my_ptr
    std::cout<<&my_ptr<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
bool my_unique_ptr<T>::isNullptr()
{
    return (my_ptr==nullptr);
}
```

this is "my_memory.hpp"

```
#ifndef my_memory_hpp
#define my_memory_hpp

template <typename T>
class my_unique_ptr
{
    public:
        bool isNullptr();
        my_unique_ptr();
        ~my_unique_ptr();
        explicit my_unique_ptr(T *input);
    private:
        T* my_ptr;
};

#include "my_memory.cpp"
#endif /* my_memory_hpp */
```

and this is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_memory.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    my_unique_ptr<char> uptr{new char{'a'}};
    cout<<"address of uptr: "<<&uptr<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what is `my_unique_ptr`. I guess, it does not define `operator *`.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: I add and code! so.. should I define "operator*" inside of my "my_memory"?

Comment: Yes. Make it a member of your class. And since it is a template, the entire implementation must be in the header. No need for cpp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `operator*` for `my_unique_ptr()`.